# AnyChart Dynamic Maps

Tags: anychart

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/7.12.0/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/7.12.0/anychart-ui.min.css" />
<div id="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
    var data = anychart.data.set([
        ['Preventivo' ,'Monitoreado',22 ,"#298A08"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Estandarizado', 16, "#298A08"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Informal', 10, "#04B431"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Nulo', 4, "#FF8000"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Monitoreado', 14, "#04B431"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Estandarizado', 10, "#04B431"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Informal', 6, "#FF8000"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Nulo', 2, "#FFFF00"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Monitoreado', 6, "#FF8000"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Estandarizado', 4, "#FF8000"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Informal', 2, "#FFFF00"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Nulo', 0, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Monitoreado', -2, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Estandarizado', -2, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Informal', -2, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Nulo', -2, "#FF0000"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Monitoreado', 21, "#298A08"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Estandarizado', 15, "#04B431"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Informal', 9, "#FF8000"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Nulo', 3, "#FFFF00"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Monitoreado', 13, "#04B431"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Estandarizado', 9, "#FF8000"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Informal', 5, "#FF8000"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Nulo', 1, "#FF0000"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Monitoreado', 5, "#FF8000"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Estandarizado', 3, "#FFFF00"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Informal', 1, "#FF0000"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Nulo', -1, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Monitoreado', -3, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Estandarizado', -3, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Informal', -3, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Nulo', -3, "#FF0000"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Monitoreado', 23, "#298A08"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Estandarizado', 17, "#298A08"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Informal', 11, "#04B431"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Nulo', 5, "#FF8000"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Monitoreado', 15, "#04B431"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Estandarizado', 11, "#04B431"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Informal', 7, "#FF8000"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Nulo', 3, "#FFFF00"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Monitoreado', 7, "#FF8000"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Estandarizado', 5, "#FF8000"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Informal', 3, "#FFFF00"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Nulo', 1, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Monitoreado', -1, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Estandarizado', -1, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Informal', -1, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Nulo', -1, "#FF0000"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Monitoreado', 20, "#298A08"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Estandarizado', 14, "#04B431"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Informal', 8, "#FF8000"],
        ['Preventivo', 'Nulo', 2, "#FFFF00"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Monitoreado', 12, "#04B431"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Estandarizado', 8, "#FF8000"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Informal', 4, "#FF8000"],
        ['Correctivo', 'Nulo', 0, "#FF0000"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Monitoreado', 4, "#FF8000"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Estandarizado', 2, "#FFFF00"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Informal', 0, "#FF0000"],
        ['Detectivo', 'Nulo', -2, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Monitoreado', -4, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Estandarizado', -4, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Informal', -4, "#FF0000"],
        ['Inexistente', 'Nulo', -4, "#FF0000"]
    ]);

    stage = anychart.graphics.create("container");
    var count = 2;
    for (i=0; i<2; i++){
        for (j=0; j<2; j++){
            var dataSet = data.mapAs({x: [1],y: [0], heat: [2], fill: [3]});
            count++;
            var chart = anychart.heatMap(dataSet);
            chart.container(stage);
            chart.bounds(50*i + '%', 50*j + '%', "50%", "50%");
            chart.draw();
        }
    };
});
```

I have a problem, apply the same example, and continue giving problems, because it draws on, ie draws the same, which is wrong. Could you send me an example with this data to show 4 different graphs?

```
stage = anychart.graphics.create("container")...;
```

Comment: You should paste the code in the question and also be more specific about the behavior you're expecting and give more detail on the errors that you're getting.

Comment: My problem is, I need to generate 4 maps, in this example I generate 4 maps, but one on top of the other (superposition), I want them to be 4 maps but correctly, check the example.
[Example][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/g4ex62h0/2/

**See the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diego, all you need - is to get the appropriate part of data for each chart. If you'll apply the [data()](https://api.anychart.com/latest/anychart.data.Set#data) method, you'll get the array, so you can easily get the data, e.g. with the [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method:

```
data.data().slice(16*count, 16*(count+1));
```

This simple example illustrates the idea:
http://jsfiddle.net/g4ex62h0/4/