# ANY CHART dynamic Draw HeadMaps

Tags: anychart

What I need is the following:

I have the data as it appears in the question, my problem is, I need to generate 4 (headmaps), as it appears in the example, the problem is that in my example appear those 4 (headmaps), one on top of the other, ie appear Repeated. What I need is to generate 4 or more maps, but not to be repeated ..

My problem is, I need to generate 4 maps, in this example I generate 4 maps, but one on top of the other (superposition), I want them to be 4 maps but correctly, check the example

My code

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {

var data = anychart.data.set([
['Preventivo'     ,'Monitoreado'    ,22 ,"#298A08"],
['Preventivo'     ,'Estandarizado'  ,16 ,"#298A08"],
['Preventivo'     ,'Informal'       ,10 ,"#04B431"],
['Preventivo'     ,'Nulo'       ,4  ,"#FF8000"],
['Correctivo'     ,'Monitoreado'    ,14 ,"#04B431"],
['Correctivo'     ,'Estandarizado'  ,10 ,"#04B431"],
['Correctivo'     ,'Informal'       ,6  ,"#FF8000"],
['Correctivo'     ,'Nulo'       ,2  ,"#FFFF00"],
['Detectivo'        ,'Monitoreado'  ,6  ,"#FF8000"],
['Detectivo'        ,'Estandarizado'    ,4  ,"#FF8000"],
['Detectivo'        ,'Informal'     ,2  ,"#FFFF00"],
['Detectivo'        ,'Nulo'     ,0  ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Monitoreado'  ,-2 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Estandarizado'    ,-2 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Informal'     ,-2 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente', 'Nulo'      ,-2 ,"#FF0000"],
['Preventivo'     ,'Monitoreado'    ,21 ,"#298A08"],
['Preventivo'     ,'Estandarizado'  ,15 ,"#04B431"],
['Preventivo'     ,'Informal'       ,9  ,"#FF8000"],
['Preventivo'     ,'Nulo'       ,3  ,"#FFFF00"],
['Correctivo'     ,'Monitoreado'    ,13 ,"#04B431"],
['Correctivo'     ,'Estandarizado'  ,9  ,"#FF8000"],
['Correctivo'     ,'Informal'       ,5  ,"#FF8000"],
['Correctivo'     ,'Nulo'       ,1  ,"#FF0000"],
['Detectivo'        ,'Monitoreado'  ,5  ,"#FF8000"],
['Detectivo'        ,'Estandarizado'    ,3  ,"#FFFF00"],
['Detectivo'        ,'Informal'     ,1  ,"#FF0000"],
['Detectivo'        ,'Nulo'     ,-1 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Monitoreado'  ,-3 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Estandarizado'    ,-3 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Informal'     ,-3 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Nulo'     ,-3 ,"#FF0000"],
['Preventivo'  ,'Monitoreado'   ,23 ,"#298A08"],
['Preventivo'    ,'Estandarizado'   ,17 ,"#298A08"],
['Preventivo'    ,'Informal'        ,11 ,"#04B431"],
['Preventivo'    ,'Nulo'        ,5  ,"#FF8000"],
['Correctivo'    ,'Monitoreado' ,15 ,"#04B431"],
['Correctivo'    ,'Estandarizado'   ,11 ,"#04B431"],
['Correctivo'    ,'Informal'        ,7  ,"#FF8000"],
['Correctivo'     ,'Nulo'       ,3  ,"#FFFF00"],
['Detectivo'        ,'Monitoreado'  ,7  ,"#FF8000"],
['Detectivo'        ,'Estandarizado'    ,5  ,"#FF8000"],
['Detectivo'        ,'Informal'     ,3  ,"#FFFF00"],
['Detectivo'        ,'Nulo'     ,1  ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Monitoreado'  ,-1 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Estandarizado'    ,-1 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Informal'     ,-1 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Nulo'     ,-1 ,"#FF0000"],
['Preventivo'   ,'Monitoreado'  ,20 ,"#298A08"],
['Preventivo'   ,'Estandarizado'    ,14 ,"#04B431"],
['Preventivo'   ,'Informal'     ,8  ,"#FF8000"],
['Preventivo'   ,'Nulo'     ,2  ,"#FFFF00"],
['Correctivo'   ,'Monitoreado'  ,12 ,"#04B431"],
['Correctivo'   ,'Estandarizado'    ,8  ,"#FF8000"],
['Correctivo'   ,'Informal'     ,4  ,"#FF8000"],
['Correctivo'   ,'Nulo'     ,0  ,"#FF0000"],
['Detectivo'    ,'Monitoreado'  ,4  ,"#FF8000"],
['Detectivo'    ,'Estandarizado'    ,2  ,"#FFFF00"],
['Detectivo'    ,'Informal'     ,0  ,"#FF0000"],
['Detectivo'  ,'Nulo'       ,-2 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Monitoreado'  ,-4 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Estandarizado'    ,-4 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Informal'     ,-4 ,"#FF0000"],
['Inexistente'  ,'Nulo'     ,-4 ,"#FF0000"]
 ]);

stage = anychart.graphics.create("container");
var count = 2;
 for (i=0; i<2; i++){
   for (j=0; j<2; j++){
       var dataSet = data.mapAs({x: [1],y: [0], heat: [2], fill: [3]});
       count++;
       var chart = anychart.heatMap(dataSet);
       chart.container(stage);
       chart.bounds(50*i + '%', 50*j + '%', "50%", "50%");
       chart.draw();

 }};
 });
```

This link is the complete example.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/g4ex62h0/2/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AnyChart Dynamic Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099009/anychart-dynamic-maps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diego, all you need - is to get the appropriate part of data for each chart. If you'll apply the data() method, you'll get the array, so you can easily get the data, e.g. with the slice() method:

```
data.data().slice(16*count, 16*(count+1));
```

This simple example illustrates the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/g4ex62h0/4/

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42122594/4687348) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)